# registerCpRoutes gives 404

Tags: plugin-development

In my main plugin file I have the following code in my registerCpRoutes fucntion:

```
public function registerCpRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'campaignreports/subscribers/detail\/(?P<listId>\d+)' => 'campaignreports/subscribers/_detail/'
    );
}
```

I have a _detail.html template located in /templates/subscribers/_detail.html

For some reason this doesn't seem to work. I keep on getting a "Page not found" error.
As far as I can tell I have followed [the docs on dynamic routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/templates#dynamic-url-routing)
Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

PS: I have uninstalled & reinstalled the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh week, fresh look at things. I failed to notice that the regex was set to \d and my campaignmonitor "id" contained alphabetic characters.
Changing it to \w fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are escaping the / right in front of the regex. Maybe thats the issue?

Comment: Also I think you have to remove the trailing / after _detail